# threejs instance multiple objects with different sizes and positions

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

just yesterday i started to tried the InstancedBufferGeometry method because i want to render thousand of objects with a good performance.
In my case i want to instance cube geometries with different heights of each other.
At moment i tried this code

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('instancing', {
  schema: {
    count: {type: 'int', default: 10000}
  },

  init: function () {
    this.count = this.data.count;
    this.model = null;
  },

  update: function () {
    if (this.model !== null) { return; }

    var data = this.data;
    var el = this.el;

    var count = this.count;

    var geometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();
    geometry.copy(new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 5, 10));

    var translateArray = new Float32Array(count*3);
    var vectorArray = new Float32Array(count*3);
    var colorArray = new Float32Array(count*3);
    var vertices = new Float32Array(count * 24);

    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
      var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 50);
      vertices[i*3+0] = 10;
      vertices[i*3+1] = y;
      vertices[i*3+2] = 10;

      vertices[i*24+3] = 10;
      vertices[i*24+4] = y;
      vertices[i*24+5] = -10;

      vertices[i*24+6] = 10;
      vertices[i*24+7] = -y;
      vertices[i*24+8] = 10;

      vertices[i*24+9] = 10;
      vertices[i*24+10] = -y;
      vertices[i*24+11] = -10;

      vertices[i*24+12] = -10;
      vertices[i*24+13] = y;
      vertices[i*24+14] = -10;

      vertices[i*24+15] = -10;
      vertices[i*24+16] = y;
      vertices[i*24+17] = 10;

      vertices[i*24+18] = -10;
      vertices[i*24+19] = -y;
      vertices[i*24+20] = -10;

      vertices[i*24+21] = -10;
      vertices[i*24+22] = -y;
      vertices[i*24+23] = 10;
   }

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      translateArray[i*3+0] = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 100.0;
      translateArray[i*3+1] = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 100.0;
      translateArray[i*3+2] = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 100.0;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      vectorArray[i*3+0] = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 100.0;
      vectorArray[i*3+1] = (Math.random() + 1.5) * 100.0;
      vectorArray[i*3+2] = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 100.0;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      colorArray[i*3+0] = Math.random();
      colorArray[i*3+1] = Math.random();
      colorArray[i*3+2] = Math.random();
    }

    geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(vertices, 24, 1));
    geometry.addAttribute('translate', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(translateArray, 3, 1));
    geometry.addAttribute('vector', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(vectorArray, 3, 1));
    geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(colorArray, 3, 1));

    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: {
        time: {value: 0}
      },
      vertexShader: [
        'attribute vec3 translate;',
        'attribute vec3 vector;',
        'attribute vec3 color;',
        'uniform float time;',
        'varying vec3 vColor;',
        'const float g = 9.8 * 1.5;',
        'void main() {',
        '  vec3 offset;',
        '  offset.xz = vector.xz * time;',
        '  offset.y = vector.y * time - 0.5 * g * time * time;',
        '  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position + translate + offset, 1.0 );',
        '  vColor = color;',
  '}'
      ].join('\n'),
      fragmentShader: [
        'varying vec3 vColor;',
        'void main() {',
        '  gl_FragColor = vec4( vColor, 1.0 );',
        '}'
      ].join('\n')
    });

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    this.model = mesh;
    el.setObject3D('mesh', mesh);
    el.emit('model-loaded', {format:'mesh', model: mesh});
  },

  tick: function(time, delta) {
    if (this.model === null) { return; }

    var mesh = this.model;
    mesh.material.uniforms.time.value = (mesh.material.uniforms.time.value + delta / 1000) % 30.0;
  }
});
```

but i have this error

**[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0x17d96d74a000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : glVertexAttribPointer: size GL_INVALID_VALUE
(index):1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0x17d96d74a000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElementsInstancedANGLE: attached to enabled attrib 1 : no buffer**

im a recruit to threejs low level functions. i started with aframe but unfortunately i see that in my case the normal use of this framework is not sufficent to have good performances.

my goal is to have multiple cubes with different sizes in different positions. any suggestion? thanks in advance

with TheJim solution.

[image]

Comment: Is `update` running every frame? Then you have a problem, yeah.. Why arent u just using `THREE.BoxGeometry` if you just want cubes?

Comment: I elaborated on one of MrDoob's jsfiddles here: http://jsfiddle.net/y03swtfx/1/

Comment: @Arg0n i tried in the `init()` function but i have the same error . thanks for the code but this mode is too much inefficent because there is a mesh for only single geometry. i''ve tried to merge all geometries to one big geometry then to use only one single mesh. this method is fast but still not sufficent. I see that the most efficent method to create thousand of figures is the "instancing" method but im new to this technique. this is an example of what i said  [https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing.html

Answer (score 0):

First, `position` should not be re-defined. `ShaderMaterial` injects common attributes, including `position`, and your definition conflicts with that. If you'd like to define *everything* yourself, look into [`RawShaderMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/RawShaderMaterial).

Second, remember, you're defining the vertices, indices, and normals for ONE cube, then using shaders/instancing to manipulate the rest. Only instance-specific data should be defined as `InstancedBufferAttribute`s.

Take a look at this example:

```
var cubeGeo = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry().copy(new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10));
//cubeGeo.maxInstancedCount = 8;

cubeGeo.addAttribute("cubePos", new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array([
  25, 25, 25,
  25, 25, -25, -25, 25, 25, -25, 25, -25,
  25, -25, 25,
  25, -25, -25, -25, -25, 25, -25, -25, -25
]), 3, 1));

var vertexShader = [
  "precision highp float;",
  "",
  "uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;",
  "uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;",
  "",
  "attribute vec3 position;",
  "attribute vec3 cubePos;",
  "",
  "void main() {",
  "",
  " gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( cubePos + position, 1.0 );",
  "",
  "}"
].join("\n");
var fragmentShader = [
  "precision highp float;",
  "",
  "void main() {",
  "",
  " gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);",
  "",
  "}"
].join("\n");

var mat = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {},
  vertexShader: vertexShader,
  fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
  transparent: true
});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, mat);

scene.add(mesh);
```

Like you, I've created a cube (just one cube). I then add an `InstancedBufferAttribute` named `cubePos` which will change the positions of the cubes (`cubePos` applies to ALL vertices in this example). This is similar to your `translate` attribute.

As far as stretching the cubes, it looks like you may be close with your `position` attribute. It may work as you expect if you simply give it a name that is not built-in, like `stretch`.

Personally, since it looks like you're stretching it equally in both directions, I'd probably just pass in a single value per instance, and use it to scale the cube in both Y directions.

Comment: thanks. i've already tried a similar solution. the strange thing is that when i use this code i have 4 box shapes instead of a single resized figure. i've updated my first post if you want try to see the result. what i want is a single box with vertices in the same position of the boxes in the image

Comment: @DiagonalThink Just so you know, the code I provided wasn't a solution, it was just an example so you could see how instancing works.