# index is undefined when using InstancedBufferGeometry

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to use InstancedBufferGeometry to add many copies of the same object (which will eventually be a tree) with different position and scale properties to a model. For my example I'm just starting with three objects, but when I've got it working as expected it'll be using much more than that with values coming from an external source.

I've been trying to follow the various examples online, including https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing.html and [threejs instance multiple objects with different sizes and positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035184/threejs-instance-multiple-objects-with-different-sizes-and-positions) but I'm getting "index is undefined".

My example page is at https://haddons.net/threejs/instanced.html and the relevant bits of code are:

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  precision highp float;

  uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
  uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

  attribute vec3 position;
  attribute vec3 scale;

  void main(){
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
  }
</script>
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  precision highp float;
  void main(){
    gl_FragColor = color;
  }
</script>
```

And also:

```
  var treePositions = [ -407, -1426, 0, 599, -1408, 237.637607058056, -207, -1400, 219.96670816865293 ];
  var treeScales = [ 13.253584152956366, 13.253584152956366, 13.253584152956366, 12.133671566054215, 12.133671566054215,
    12.133671566054215, 9.152234330749572, 9.152234330749572, 9.152234330749572 ];

  var treeGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.2,0.2,1,16,1);
  var treeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x885522});
  var tree = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  tree.rotation.x += Math.PI / 2;

  var instanceNum = 3;

  var geometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();
  geometry.copy(treeGeometry);
  geometry.maxInstancedCount = instanceNum;
  geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute( new Float32Array(treePositions), 3));
  geometry.addAttribute( 'scale', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute( new Float32Array(treeScales), 3));

  var material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial( {
    uniforms: {},
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
  });

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  scene.add( mesh );
```

Obviously I haven't yet figured out how to apply any of the attributes that I'm trying to pass in, so the vertexShader and fragementShader snippets are likely entirely wrong.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a

```
geometry.setIndex(some array);
```

that defines how are your vertices connected.

Comment: Thanks, any hints on how I would define that array? I've tried searching through the examples in the three.js repo for setIndex to try and understand how it works in this case, but haven't been able to see how it would apply here. Is this because I've done geometry.copy(treeGeometry) and that "Copies vertices, faces and uvs into this geometry. It does not copy any other properties of the geometry"?

Comment: well that depends on how your triangles are defined in the position array. if you have just listed all the points of your triangles in the position array then the index for this example would be `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`